# How do I pass varied parameters when constructing objects via reflection?

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I have a situation where I use reflection to create objects at run-time based on their fully qualified class names. All the objects extend the same abstract class, so their general type is known at compile time but the concrete implementation is determined by the class name supplied at run-time.

The abstract class provides one static method named create, that takes the class name and other parameters with which to construct the concrete object. Each Response has an actual type A and a storage type S. The actual type is the "proper" representation of the data in Java and the storage type is the thing that gets stored in the database. E.g. A might be a Date object and S might be the same Date objected converted to a Long for storage in SQLite.

Here's a simplified representation:

```
public abstract class Response<A, S> {

    public Response(String clazz, Object value, boolean actual) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        if (actual) {
           actualValue = (A) value;
        } else {
            actualValue = toActualValue((S) value);
        }
    }

    public static Response create(String clazz, Object value) {
        //create response by reflection
        return response;
    }
}
```

This was working okay until I now when I have to deal with the fact that in addition to the two parameters that each Response implementation takes, some Response implementations now need to take additional parameters.

These additional parameters cannot be passed via setter methods as they are typically used in the package private method `toActualValue()` that is called from within the abstract Response constructor.

I've considered using the Builder pattern to handler the optional parameters, but then I would need a way to determine which Response implementations take which parameters - and I can't think of a clean way to provide that information. Maybe I am thinking about this entirely wrong. Any helpful insights or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using a parameter object as parameter for the constructor. It will have all possible parameters as members, and you just fill the ones needed. This will protect you from any other like changes to be made in the future.

Comment: The thing I don't like about this approach is that it doesn't make it apparent what the dependencies of each type of response are, which is bad for unit testing and readability. And I should point out that currently this is the solution I'm using, but I don't like it very much for the stated reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the arbitrary number of arguments?

```
public TestClass(String clazz, Object value, boolean actual, Object... parms) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        if (actual) {
           actualValue = (A) value;
        } else {
            //actualValue = toActualValue((S) value, parms);
        }
    }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: Again as I have mentioned in my other comment, the ability to be explicit about the exact nature of dependencies is important to me, and this approach doesn't quite provide that.